# Fill username and password in input tag using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I have elements in my code like this :

```
<input data-v-d6c12922="" type="text" name="account" placeholder="账号" class="username">  
<input data-v-d6c12922="" type="password" name="password" placeholder="密码" class="password">
```

I used this, but it's not working.

```
userElem = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/input")
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/input"}
```

How can I auto-fill the username and password?

Thank you.

Comment: 1) Please state *what* is not working. Is it not finding the element? Or is it not inputting the expected value? If it is the latter, we do not see your minimal example of inputting a value.

Comment: There is no element finding, this is the error : selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/input"}

Comment: It's going to be hard for anyone to help you if you don't also provide a link

Comment: This is the link : http://123.60.12.11:10016/#/login?url=http%3A%2F%2F123.60.12.11%3A10016%2F%23%2FMySociety%2FSocietyDetail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue might be you are trying to find the element before it is visible.

You can wait for the element to be visible using the code below (I am also finding the ID by CLASS_NAME instead of XPATH, and capturing a screenshot to show the fields have been filled out)

```
driver.get("http://123.60.12.11:10016/#/login?url=http%3A%2F%2F123.60.12.11%3A10016%2F%23%2FMySociety%2FSocietyDetail")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
username = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "username")))
username.send_keys("test@email.com")
pw = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "password")))
pw.send_keys("asdasd")

driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")
```

[image: Working example]

Comment: I already tried to used it by class name, but it's not working.
This is the error : selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".username"}

Comment: You might need to add a wait to wait until the element is visible, as the page is slow to load. I updated my answer with working code, tested on your website. Let me know if it helps!